# How to fix "An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred... Java returned: -1073741819" error on java?

Tags: java, java-runtime-compiler

While working on a Java Swing project I encountered the following runtime error "An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred... Java returned: -1073741819".
Project environment: Netbeans 12, jdk1.8.0_211, poi 4.1 on windows 10

 I cannot reproduce this error.

```
An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW (0xc00000fd) at pc=0x0000000050d34ef7, pid=218832, tid=0x000000000004488c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_211-b12) (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.211-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x214ef7]C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: -1073741819
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 15 seconds)
```

Comment: please have a look at [ASK]

Comment: Worth upgrading to 8u281. Can you reproduce this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Netbeans, everything works fine.